# Move a dot along a path

Tags: geometry, pythagorean-triples

I have a multi-point, straight line path - to keep it simple it has three points, A B & C.

- A = 60,410
- B = 127.5,410
- C = 195,240

This is the 'template' path, I need to animate a dot moving along this path, lets keep it simple and say there are 10 steps.

So, step 1 = point A and step 10 = point C, I need to calculate equidistant points along this path.

What is the most efficient way to determine each equidistant point?

Comment: i recommend this question be closed a) because i've solved it using a multi-step process and b) because i don't think the problem was obvious and the proposed solutions make no sense to me

Comment: i will not further clarify feel free to close/delete

Answer (score 1):

There are many paths that pass through those three points. There's an arc of a circle, for instance. You could take that arc and divide it into 10 equal parts. There's also the graph of some quadratic in $x$, but finding arclengths on that is likely to be a bit messy. There's the Catmull-Rom spline through those 3 points (with various end-conditions possible), but finding arclengths on that is likely to be almost impossible.

In short: I think you need to clarify the problem and nail down exactly which path you're speaking of; only then can we hope to tell you how to calculate equidistant points.

(By the way, do you mean "straight line distance" or "distance along the curved path itself"?)

Comment: straight line multi-point path, sorry i assumed this would be obvious

Comment: @pstanton The issue is that $a$, $b$, and $c$ aren't collinear; there's no single straight line that runs through all three.

Comment: i am aware it is a multi step process - i have solved it for myself if you see my own answer below

Comment: Typically a path like that is called a "polyline" or "piecewise linear path"; saying that might have made your question less ambiguous. As for your actual work below --- that's exactly the code everyone has to write. I've written it a half-dozen times myself. So no need to go beating yourself up looking for something more elegant and math-y.

Answer (score 1):

Appologies, I am a programmer, not a mathimatician so I am not used to marking up using standard notation. here is some pseudo code to describe how i solved the problem.

first step is to calculate the total distance of the path so distance from point[n] to point[n+1]:

```
for p in paths
    dx = points[p+1].x - points[p].x
    dy = points[p+1].y - points[p].y

    distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2))
```

then i need to figure out how far along this total distance the dot is up to

```
step = n
stepDistance = (totalDistance / totalSteps) * step
```

then i need to determine which segment of the path this distance falls upon and how far along that segment the dot should be placed

```
dist = 0
for p in paths
    dist += path.distance
    if stepDistance <= dist
         stepPath = p
         stepPathDist = stepDistance - (dist - path.distance)
```

lastly, I resolve the coordinates of the point along the path segment by working out the paths angle and moving along this angle the correct distance

```
dx = points[stepPath+1].x - points[stepPath].x
dy = points[stepPath+1].y - points[stepPath].y
angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx)
x = (Math.cos(angle) * stepPathDist) + points[stepPath].x
y = (Math.sin(angle) * stepPathDist) + points[stepPath].y
```

this works however i'm sure can be expressed much more mathematically, feel free to improve!

Comment: One small mathematical relation here: this is essentially a "discretized" (i.e., broken into separate pieces, rather than being done on a continuous basis using calculus) version of something called "parameterization by arclength," a standard technique in differential geometry. The fact that it's most easily expressed algorithmically doesn't make it any less mathematical. You could even be justified in "accepting" your own answer (although I don't think you'll get any points for doing so...I can't recall the rules), leaving the solution here for others to find in the future.

Comment: @JohnHughes thanks, i agree  - if someone can recommend a better solution than my own i'd gladly give it the tick, in fact i voted to delete the question since i believe it is more of a procedural rather than mathematical question.

Answer (score 0):

### Method

If it is an straight line path then all you need is the start point $\vec{p}_1$ and the end point $\vec{p}_n$

1. Find the distance between the end points $\ell = \| \vec{p}_n - \vec{p}_1 \|$
2. Find the direction of the line $\vec{e} = \frac{\vec{p}_n - \vec{p}_1 }{\ell} $
3. Find the *i*-th point like this

$$ \vec{p}_i = \vec{p}_1 + (\vec{p}_n - \vec{p}_1) \frac{i-1}{n-1} = \vec{p}_1 +  \vec{e} \ell \;\frac{i-1}{n-1}  $$

### Example

If you have $\vec{p}_1 = (60,410)$ and $\vec{p}_n = (195,240)$ and you want to split into $n=10$ points (9 segments) then

1. $\ell = \| (155, -170) \| = 230.0543$
2. $\vec{e} = (155, -170)/230.0543 = (0.6738, -0.7390)$
3. The points are $$\begin{align} \vec{p}_1 &= (60,410) \\
   \vec{p}_2 &= (60,410) + (155, -170) \frac{1}{9} = (57.2222,  391.1111) \\
   \vec{p}_3 &= (60,410) + (155, -170) \frac{2}{9} = (74.4444,  372.2222) \\
   \vdots \\
   \vec{p}_9 &= (60,410) + (155, -170) \frac{8}{9} = (177.7778, 258.8889) \\
   \vec{p}_{10} &= (60,410) + (155, -170) = (195,240)
   \end{align} $$

Comment: This solves a problem that the OP did not ask (or at most a very special case of the problem OP did ask).

Comment: @JohnHughes "I have a multi-point, _straight line path_ ... What is the most efficient way to determine each equidistant point?" so what part of the OP question I did not answer?

Comment: If you look at the actual data offered, what the OP meant was that "each segment between two points was a straight line" (as opposed to a sequence of Bezier curves, for instance). The method offered by this answer, applied to the first and last points $A$ and $C$, turns out not to pass through the middle point $B$, as you can see by looking at the second coordinate of each point. Sometimes a phrase like "straight line path" can mean different things to different people, and providing a helpful answer requires a close reading.

Comment: I misunderstood the question then. The problem is that the correct answer is not mathematical but algorithmic (as in computer code). Maybe this question needs to be migrated to [SO]. I was going for the purely mathematical interpretation of the question.

Comment: Well, the OP was *hoping* that there was some "purely mathematical" approach; often new posters don't actually *know* whether their questions are mathematical or algorithmic, etc., and we help them best by helping them understand. BTW, the thing that the correct answer describes is essentially the discretization of "parametrization by arclength", so there's a case for saying that it *is* mathematical; just that it's best expressed algorithmically.

Comment: @JohnHughes since you understand this answer (i'm not sure i do) do you think this is a better answer than my own? if so i'd gladly give the tick...

Comment: No, I don't think so. It solves the problem ONLY if the three points on your path all lie on a straight line; in that case, it solves the problem by ignoring all but the first and last, and then spacing the points equally -- pretty much what your code does for each segment.

Comment: I agree, but I am keeping it here for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

In *Mathematica*:

```
a = {60,410};
b = {127.5,410};
c = {195,240};

Animate[
 Graphics[{{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[#]} & /@ {a, b, c},
   If[0 < t < .5, {Point[(1 - 2 t) a + 2 t b]}, 
    Point[(2 - 2 t ) b + (-1 + 2 t) c]]}], 
{t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: i don't understand this notation sorry

Comment: The solution puts 5 equally-spaced points on the first segment, and 5 more on the next segment. This doesn't work, of course, if the segments have different lengths, because the "steps" along the two segments have different lengths.